# Manually italic fonts inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape, transform

In the Transfer-Mode (`CTRL+t`) in Photoshop i can hold `CTRL` and drag the Edge of my font element to get it italic. [image: Screenshot in Photoshop]

I can't figure out how to do that in inkscape.

(Italic is not available for my font.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click text, click text again.

Move the top handle to the right.

[image: Top handle]

Result

[image: shear result]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/inkscape-text-tricks.php):

1. Select the text using the *Create and Edit text tool* (<kbd>F8</kbd>).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to italicise. If your font does not come with italics, this just skews the font as desired.